# How can I run a command once fs is done writing to a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, inquirer, inquirerjs

Here is the code in question:

```
        const scriptFiles = fs.readdirSync(scriptsPath)
            .filter(file => file.endsWith(".sql"));

        for (const file of scriptFiles) {

            var data = fs.readFileSync(`${scriptsPath}/${file}`, 'utf8');
            fs.appendFile(`${scriptsPath}/Hotfix.sql`, data.toString() + "\n", (err) => {
                if (err) throw new Error(err)
                console.log('Appending ' + file + '...')
            })

            process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
        }

        console.log(`start ${scriptsPath}/Hotfix.sql`)
        exec(`start ${scriptsPath}/Hotfix.sql`)
```

The problem that I'm running into is that it is attempting to open/start `scriptsPath/Hotfix.sql` before anything has been appended to the file. For example, here is the output from the console.log()s I've added to the script:

```
start scriptsPath/Hotfix.sql
Appending file1.sql...    
Appending file2.sql...
```

is there a way I can have the script wait until the for loop has completed before attempting to execute the command?

Comment: You're already using the `*Sync` versions so why did you then switch to the async `.appendFile()` instead of sticking with `.appendFileSync()`?

Comment: The (imho) better way would be to understand how asynchronous code/functions work and how to work with them. This would then also hopefully lead to the conclusion that it should be `console.log('File ' + file + ' has been appended')` and not `'Appending...'` (and at which place of your script you can safely work with the appended file)

Comment: @Andreas It's been a year or two since I've had the opportunity to work with Node and I completely forgot that appendFileSync() existed. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the ***appendFile()*** asynchronous method with the ***appendFileSync()*** synchronous method so that code waits until the loop has completed.

```js
const scriptFiles = fs.readdirSync(scriptsPath)
  .filter(file => file.endsWith(".sql"));

for (const file of scriptFiles) {

  var data = fs.readFileSync(`${scriptsPath}/${file}`, 'utf8');
  fs.appendFileSync(`${scriptsPath}/Hotfix.sql`, data.toString() + "\n");

  process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
}

console.log(`start ${scriptsPath}/Hotfix.sql`)
exec(`start ${scriptsPath}/Hotfix.sql`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use `.appendFileSync()` and remove the `(err)=>` callback, or write your code as async entirely.

There is an async version of the `fs` API, you can access it via `require('fs').promises`.

In that case, you will have to use `await`, your code must be an async function. For an utility script that only does one thing, the benefit of doing it that way is questionable.